# Flutter Stack with Expended widget got error

Tags: flutter, dart

I got "Each child must be laid out exactly once." and "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" for following code.

I want to Bottom Panel to persistence for all screen. So I create Base Widget. It is working fine if I don't use stack. I used Stack because my bottom panel has rounded corner and want to make corner transparent.

So now bottom panel is transparent but got the error.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Expanded(
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
      const Positioned(
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        child: BottomPanel(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Positioned.fill instead of Positioned with Expanded as a child instead.
Do it like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned.fll(
        child: child, // if you want to specify this widget height add it here
      ),
      const Positioned(
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        child: BottomPanel(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Positioned.fill is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Expanded` widget inside `positioned` or `stack` widget. You have to wrap that `Expanded` widget in `Row`, `flex` or `Column` if you want to use `Expanded` or try another way to achieve this task

> Using an Expanded widget makes a child of a Row, Column, or Flex
> expand to fill the available space along the main axis (e.g.,
> horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column). If multiple
> children are expanded, the available space is divided among them
> according to the flex factor.

Comment: Noted with thanks.